# Kubernetes Helm chart if condition inside an array

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to update this chart  :

```
k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: '[
            { "name" : "ext", "ips": {{ .Values.global.extoamlancas0 | quote }}, "interface": "e1"},
            { "name" : "ext-app", "ips": {{ .Values.global.extapplancas0 | quote }}, "interface": "e3"},
            { "name" : "int-", "ips": {{ .Values.global.intoamlancas0 | quote }}, "interface": "e2"}
         ]'
Here
 if {{- if Values.a }} then I want "ips" to be in an array i.e 
{ "name" : "ext-", "ips": [ {{ .Values.global.extoamlancas0 | quote }} ], "interface": "e1"}

else 
{ "name" : "ext", "ips": {{ .Values.global.extoamlancas0 | quote }}, "interface": "e1"}
```

I want this to be done for all other 2 ips too.

Answer (score 3):

In the values.yaml file you need to specify an array ips like this:

```
ips:
  - address: 192.168.1.1
    name: no1

  - address: 192.168.1.2
    name: no2
```

And in the templates file you can loop like this:

```
{{- range .Values.ips }}
  - name: {{ .name }}
    address: {{ .address }}
{{- end }}
```

Below is the snippet from golang docs: [template - Go | range](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions)

> {{range pipeline}} T1 {{end}}     The value of the pipeline must be an
> array, slice, map, or channel.    If the value of the pipeline has
> length zero, nothing is output;   otherwise, dot is set to the
> successive elements of the array,     slice, or map and T1 is executed.
> If the value is a map and the     keys are of basic type with a defined
> order, the elements will be   visited in sorted key order.
>
> {{range pipeline}} T1 {{else}} T0 {{end}}     The value of the pipeline
> must be an array, slice, map, or channel.     If the value of the
> pipeline has length zero, dot is unaffected and   T0 is executed;
> otherwise, dot is set to the successive elements  of the array, slice,
> or map and T1 is executed.